# Linking *.dll.a file in VS using Premake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, linker, premake

I'm trying to link to a file with a .dll.a extension (libjulia.dll.a). When I add the file directly in the VS project under the *Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies* property it works fine. However, when I add the file into the *links* property in premake it always adds .lib to the end of the file. It writes *libjulia.dll.a.lib* to the *Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies* property, which of course breaks everything.

I've tried writing just *julia.dll* and many other ways of writing the file's name and either the same problem occurs or it just doesn't write the file to the property at all. I'm not very experienced with premake so perhaps there is some intended way to solve this?

Comment: ".... it works fine." Then why not do it like that?

Comment: It works fine when I write it into the VS project generated by premake. However, having to change the VS project after premake has generated it kind of defeats the point of using premake.

Comment: From Premake documentation: `When specifying libraries, system-specific decorations, such as prefixes or file extensions, should be omitted. Premake will synthesize the correct format based on the target platform automatically.` Looks like they don't give you a chance. May be you can use `#pragma comment( lib...)` instead?

Comment: The problem is that premake assigns the wrong file extension. However, your suggestion to use #pragma comment Is something I really should have thought of myself, sorry lol. That has solved it. So thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might still use [`linkoptions`](https://premake.github.io/docs/linkoptions/) directly

```lua
filter "action:vs*"
    linkoptions "libjulia.dll.a"
filter "not action:vs*"
    links "julia.dll"
```